# Wrong reference of super on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I need to instantiate the second controller, from the first one. 
The initialization start in a button as show.

The code and the view are programmatically added.
The load start from a button

In the storyboard file the view are not connected

First controller, the caller

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcID") as? SecondController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Second controller, the called

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Barra di navigazione
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        self.navigationItem.title = "Title here"

        let attrs = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Nunito-Bold", size: 24)!
        ]

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attrs
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = attrs


    }
```

The code crash calling the initial view controller, several controller before in the navigation.
Looks like the controller lose the reference to the caller.
Any idea on how to verify the controller reference?

The error code, showed in the initial view, is

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Originated in the second Controller

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Just added the error code

Comment: Ad an exception breakpoint. It is likely that you simply haven’t connected an @IBOutlet

Comment: @Paulw11The IBOutlet are connected (double checked by reconnecting)

Comment: @matt the title is "Wrong reference of super in viewDidLoad" because the 8' view try to load the 1st without any reason in the super.viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error code maybe try the following

```
if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vcID") as? SecondController {
  let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Are you sure "vcID" is exact as it is on storyboard

Comment: @AlessioZ 100% the same? As in you copy and pasted it? An extra space could mess it up? Did my above code not work?

Comment: Just verified and the code suggested doen't solved the problem.
The second controller run the func super.viewDidLoad() and crash because it calls the initial view instead of the first one